# AspectJ Declaring Annotation with various Parameter values dependent on the method?

Tags: java, annotations, aspectj

I want to create an aspect, to declare some annotations to some methods, but with an variable parameter.

Annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyCousomAnnotation {
    String value() default "";
}
```

Trying to declare these annotation to methods in package: "com.foo" like this below:
But  should be the Signature of the Method, which is annotated with these annotation above.

```
declare @method : * com.foo..*(..) : @MyCustomAnnotaion(value=<MethodSignuature>)
```

Is it possible?

Tried to manipulate the "value" of the annotation with java reflection api.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is a typical instance of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898): Your are descibing what you want to do technically instead of showing code and explaining the problem you actually want to solve. What is the point of putting the method signature into an annotation? You can easily get the signature from an aspect advice (via the joinpoint instance) or even from plain Java (via reflection). You would not put an extra sticker with your name on your ID card either, would you? The name is printed on the ID card already.

Comment: As for manipulating an annotation value via reflection: Don't even try, it will not yield consistent results, and it is not meant to either. The whole idea of annotation values is that they are constants defined at compile time. If you feel a need to change them, it only tells you that your application design is flawed. Don't try to dig a whole with a hammer.